# mac automator script to copy filename to pdf author + title metadata

Tags: macos, mac, pdf, metadata

Have been looking around and cannot find a simple automator solution to copy info of a pdf's filename to the pdf's author and title metadata. Many solutions are built upon pdftk, but that util doesn't seem to be available for the mac anymore.

Any suggestions? I am not interested in Calibre and similar, I need an automator workflow that I can use in the Finder.

Answer (score 1):

You can install pdftk on OS X by using the installer from http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/.

This adds `(filename.pdf)` to the end of the author and title:

`for f in *.pdf;do pdftk "$f" dump_data_utf8|awk -v "f=$f" '/InfoKey: (Author|Title)/{print;getline;sub(/$/," ("f")")}1'|pdftk "$f" update_info_utf8 - output "new_$f";done`

This updates the title:

`echo $'InfoKey: Title\nInfoValue: new title'|pdftk input.pdf update_info_utf8 - output output.pdf`

Another option is to use exiftool:

`brew install exiftool;for f in *.pdf;do author=$(exiftool -p '$Author' "$f");title=$(exiftool -p '$Title' "$f");exiftool -Title="$title ($f)" -Author="$author ($f)" -overwrite_original "$f";done`

Comment: Ok, didn't know about exiftool; great will bake a workflow out of it!